# Arch Linux C++ read USB mice positioning data

Tags: c++, linux, usb, mouse, archlinux

I am running Arch Linux on a Raspberry and need to get the positioning data for 4 USB mice from a C++ application, as in for each individual mouse I need to know how many pixels it has moved whenever it moved. I do not have x server on my system and would prefer to leave it that way unless necessary because this is for an embedded project that does not require a GUI and I would prefer not waste space or overhead on x server.

The most useful thing I have found is this link https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt but I cannot really figure out how to make it work for my purpose. As can obviously be determined I am NOT experienced in Linux development do don't be to hard on me please.

Comment: First of all, since you don't have a display you don't have pixels. Secondly, you have to remember that a mouse only reports that it has moved X units in some direction, and you have to use those relative movements to calculate the "cursor" position yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry for the terminology but I actually mean that I want to know how many units the mouse moved , I just used the word pixel but I am obviously not revering to them. I want that movement data because this is for something else than user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You open e.g. `/dev/input/mouse0` for reading (using [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)), then [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) the structure defined in the document you linked (at the bottom of the document), it also says which header file to include.

I'm guessing you will get an event of type `EV_REL` for mouse-movement, with a code of `REL_X` or `REL_Y` for the direction of the movement, and the value is the number of units the mouse moved. Compare the timestamp to the timestamp of the previous event to see how fast it moves.

Comment: I have now implemented this with event3 because mouse0 does not work but for some reason it gives the exact same numbers for X and Y movement and it never seems to give a negative value.